# Symfony/Doctrine - QueryException - [Semantical Error] line 0, col 48 near 'pizza-mia': Error: 'pizza' is not defined

Tags: symfony, doctrine-query

I want to make this query in SQLite using DQL

```
//// src/Repository/PostRepository.php
public function hasPreviousPost($id,$slug): array
{

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM App\Entity\Post p WHERE p.id < '.$id.' AND p.slug = '.$slug);
    $posts = $query->getResult();


    return $posts;
}
```

And I call this function from the PostController like that

```
//// src/Controller/PostController.php
        $posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Post::class)->findAll();

        foreach ($posts as $post){

        $hasPreviousPost = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Post::class)->hasPreviousPost($post->id(),$post->Slug());
        }
```

But when I run the code, I get this error
" [Semantical Error] line 0, col 48 near 'pizza-mia': Error: 'pizza' is not defined. "

pizza-mia is what $slug contains, a string.

This is my Post entity.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

$countPosts = 0;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 */
class Post
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Column(unique=true)
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 * @ORM\Column(unique=true)
 */
private $postId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $slug;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $message;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean",nullable=true)
 */
private $isScheduled;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $scheduledPublishTime;


function __construct($postId,$slug,$message)
{
    global $countPosts;
    $countPosts++;
    $this->postId=$postId;
    $this->id=$countPosts;
    $this->slug=$slug;
    $this->message=$message;
    $this->isScheduled=false;
    $this->scheduledPublishTime=0;
}


public function PostId(): ?string
{
    return $this->postId;
}

public function id(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}


public function Slug(): ?string
{
    return $this->slug;
}


public function Message(): ?string
{
    return $this->message;
}


public function IsScheduled(): ?bool
{
    return $this->isScheduled;
}

public function changeIsScheduled(?bool $isScheduled): self
{
    $this->isScheduled = $isScheduled;

    return $this;
}

public function ScheduledPublishTime(): ?int
{
    return $this->scheduledPublishTime;
}

public function changeScheduledPublishTime(int $scheduledPublishTime): self
{
    $this->scheduledPublishTime = $scheduledPublishTime;

    return $this;
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please show the entity definition of your Post class? why is post::class not starting with a capital letter in your code example?

Comment: that was a typo, I apologise. I just added the Post entity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM App\Entity\Post p WHERE p.id < :id AND p.slug = :slug');
$query->setParameter('id', $id);
$query->setParameter('slug', $slug);
```

`:id` and `:slug` stand for a named parameter

My strong assumption is that you simply are missing the ' ' to have your $slug defined as string in your query. 
But using parameters like above makes it more readable as well.

Find an explanation about named or numbered parameters in the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#named-and-positional-parameters)

Comment: It gives me this error "Invalid parameter format, ? given, but :<name> or ?<num> expected." I tried to add the ' ' to $slug but that didn't work either

Comment: updated answer - which version of Doctrine are you using?

Comment: I use the latest version, 2.6.2